# ClickOnce deployment fails to install .NET 4 Full on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I have a C# application which I'm deploying using ClickOnce.
On Windows 7 (or 8) all works perfect, however on Windows XP the deployment fails when installing the .NET framework 4 (full)

I made a screenshot of the error: http://filevoid.net/#9323.png
The log file looks like:

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = Intel {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 5.1.2 {version}
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'DotNet40Full_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)':
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'DotNet40Full_TargetVersion' was not defined
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '5.1.2': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64': false
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe' is 'Install'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
EULA for components 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' was accepted.
Copying files to temporary directory "C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\VSD5.tmp\"
Downloading files to "C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\VSD5.tmp\"
(6-8-2013 9:46:07) Downloading 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe' from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=182805' to 'C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\VSD5.tmp\'
Download completed at 6-8-2013 9:46:08
Verifying file integrity of C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\VSD5.tmp\DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)', phase BeforePackage
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'DotNet40Full_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)':
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'DotNet40Full_TargetVersion' was not defined
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '5.1.2': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64': false
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe' is 'Install'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
Verifying file integrity of C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\VSD5.tmp\DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
Installing using command 'C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\VSD5.tmp\DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe' and parameters ' /q /norestart /ChainingPackage FullX64Bootstrapper /lcid 1033'
Process exited with code 5100
Status of package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' after install is 'InstallFailed'
```

I haven't got the slightest idea why or how to fix this.
Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You need XP SP 3 see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/249e0e37-40b6-4906-8b88-e2ebb2aafab1/error-while-application-setup-in-other-pcs-after-publishing-it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your XP is XP ServicePack 2. To Install .NET 4, you need to have ServicePack 3. Considering ServicePack 3 is free and 5 years old, you should insist on it. People need to get their computers up to date, an XP SP2 computer will be breached and exploited as a malware host the second you connect it to the internet.

Comment: I wish they al would do the update, preferably to Win7 or Win8.
I confirm that this was the problem, thank you for your help!